# How to filter out dictionary keys based on their frequencies in a corpus?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, corpus

So, I'm doing an assignment and I'm stuck on this part. I have a dictionary with a tuple of string as a key and a corresponding value. Now I have to filter the dictionary by removing the keys which occur less than 8 times in the documents of the Brown corpus using the paras method

I looked everywhere for it and couldn't find any pseudo code on how to do it.

```
[{('love', 'sex'): '6.77',
  ('tiger', 'cat'): '7.35',
  ('tiger', 'tiger'): '10.00',
  ('book', 'paper'): '7.46',
  ('computer', 'keyboard'): '7.62',
  ('computer', 'internet'): '7.58',
  ('plane', 'car'): '5.77',
  ('train', 'car'): '6.31',
  ('telephone', 'communication'): '7.50',
  ('television', 'radio'): '6.77',
  ('media', 'radio'): '7.42',
  ('drug', 'abuse'): '6.85',
  .
  . 
  .
```

So what I have to do with this dictionary is, I should remove the keys, whose tokens(word pairs) are not in alphabetic order, and, the word pairs(keys) where at least one of the words has a document frequency of less than 8 in the brown corpus

Comment: I can help you but can you give an (or a few) example inputs and example outputs that also covers edge cases? I'd rather not have to dive into the definitions of "Brown corpus" and "document frequency"...

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I don't understand what do you mean by input/ output for edge cases.

Comment: Nevermind for edge cases. Provide a detailed enough example input that would cover your needs and provide the output your want for that input.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The input is the dictionary you see in the question. It has 153 entires. So, what I have to do is to remove the entries in which the word pairs(keys) aren't in alphabetical order. Then, I have to calculate the frequency of documents of each word( not the pair, the single word) in a collection of documents( Brown Corpus) and remove the keys where at least one of the word in the word pair has a document frequency of less than 8

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a `document` is in this context so this answer may be flawed.

**Input:**

```
mylist = [{('love', 'sex'): '6.77',
  ('tiger', 'cat'): '7.35',
  ('tiger', 'tiger'): '10.00',
  ('book', 'paper'): '7.46',
  ('computer', 'keyboard'): '7.62',
  ('computer', 'internet'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'car'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'plane'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'train'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'television'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'radio'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'tiger'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'test1'): '7.58',
  ('computer', 'test2'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz1'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz2'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz3'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz4'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz5'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz6'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz7'): '7.58',
  ('tiger', 'tz8'): '7.58',
  ('plane', 'car'): '5.77',
  ('train', 'car'): '6.31',
  ('telephone', 'communication'): '7.50',
  ('television', 'radio'): '6.77',
  ('media', 'radio'): '7.42',
  ('drug', 'abuse'): '6.85'}]
```

**Solution:**
Note the solution must iterate over the dictionary twice (though the second loop will only go over part of the dictionary normally). I also handle each dictionary in the list as its own thing so you may need to move some of the statements around.

```
# This will be the keys we want to remove
removable_keys = set()

# This will be the number of times we see a key part (left or right)
occurences = dict()

# For each dictionary in our list
for dic in mylist:
    # For each key in that dictionary
    for key in dic:
        # If the key is not in alphabetical order
        if list(key) != sorted(list(key)):
            # We will remove that key
            removable_keys.add(key)
        # Else this is a valid key
        else:
            # Increment the number of times we have seen this key
            left, right = key
            occurences[left] = 1 if left not in occurences else occurences[left] + 1
            occurences[right] = 1 if right not in occurences else occurences[right] + 1
    # No we need to look for keys that had less than 8 occurences.
    for key in dic.keys() - removable_keys:
        left, right = key
        if occurences[left] < 8 or occurences[right] < 8:
            removable_keys.add(key)
    # Finally remove all those keys from our dict
    for key in removable_keys:
        del dic[key]
    print(dic)
```

**Output:**

```
{('tiger', 'tiger'): '10.00', ('computer', 'tiger'): '7.58'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's partly what I wanted, the document frequency part was poorly explained by me so let me be clear. A corpus is a collection of documents. In this case, the corpus is a Brown Corpus which is a collection of texts from various published articles(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus) So, each paragraph in this collection is considered a document. What I want is to compute the frequency of these documents containing the left and right word in the key, and we have to remove the keys where the document frequency for either the left or the right word is below 8

Comment: We should calculate the document frequency for a single word in the pair. We need not compute the frequency as a pair

Comment: I do not calculate them as a pair. I do them individually. Which aspect isn't working right?  If you provide the input you want and the output you expect it will make both our lives easier.

Comment: Okay. We should calculate the frequency of the number of paragraphs in which this word appears. The paragraphs are in this big collection called Brown corpus. ```list1 = brown.paras()``` This command gets all the paragraphs from the collections and stores it in the list 1 variable. When you look at list 1 the data stored is somewhat like this. ```[[['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.']],...]```

Comment: So, what I want is the number paragraphs in which the word ```love``` or any word in the dictionary appears. And if the word has the frequency of paragraphs less than 8, then the key is to be removed

Comment: Edit your question and put this information in there. AND PLEASE give an output. You keep showing what you have but you don't show the output you expect and explanations aren't very useful in this case.  Just like my answer, show input and output.

Comment: I don't have any output to show, except to say that the output should also be a dictionary with all the unwanted keys removed.

Comment: Just make one up. We don't expect an actual output but you need to show a theoretical output that for a theoretical input.

Comment: ```[{('love', 'sex'): '6.77',
  ('tiger', 'tiger'): '10.00',
  ('book', 'paper'): '7.46',
  ('computer', 'keyboard'): '7.62',
  ('computer', 'internet'): '7.58',
  ('media', 'radio'): '7.42',
  .
  . 
  .
``` This is the maximum I could do. I have removed the keys where the word pair isn't in alphabetical order. But I am not able to show the removed keys where the para frequency is less than 8. I'm really sorry :'(